# How resful service is used in CQ?

Tags: aem, restful-architecture, sling

I am new to Adobe CQ. I knew it uses Apache Sling framework. Apache Sling is RESTful framework to access a java content repository over http protocol. Can any one tell me with examples on how restful service is being used in CQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the documentation already? A good and quick start is the [Sling Cheatsheet](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/developing/sling_cheatsheet.pdf).
Regarding to CQ and the underlying JCR repository, each resource in the repository is represented as a path. You can access this resource by different means. If we start with the example projects (geometrixx in different characteristics) you can call for example `/content/geometrixx/en.html`
The extension `html` will render the resource as a html page whereas the markup is defined in a JSP. But you can also call `/content/geometrixx/en.json` or `/content/geometrixx/en.xml` to get a JSON or XML representation of this resource. You can also add selectors: In the JSON example you can call `/content/geometrixx/en.5.json` to get the hierarchy of this node up until level `5`.

I strongly advice to check out the sling documentation and if you still struggle with something ask a more precise question or better search for it as there are already some problems explained.